# In YDSE, Is taking the path difference as $d\sinθ$ a valid approximation?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment, huygens-principle

[image]

Let the distance between the slits be $d$ and the distance between the slits and the screen be $D$.

According to what has been taught to me, here as $D \gg d$, we can consider the lines $S_1P$ & $S_2P$ to be basically parallel and the line $S_2P$ has travelled $d\sinθ$ more than $S_1P$ hence $Δx = d\sinθ$. By this approximation we are also implying that as the two lines are parallel, $S_1P \sim qP$ and here lies my problem.

$ΔS_1Pq$ is a right-angled triangle where $S_1P$ is the hypotenuse and hence is slightly longer than $qP$ which is the base. This length difference can be easily neglected under normal circumstances but my argument is it is big enough to not be neglected in this case. I've been taught that the distance between the slits is in  the order of  $10^{-3}$ so $S_1q$ should also be nearly $10^{-3}$ considering $θ$ to be very small ($\cosθ \sim 1$) and let $qp$ ~ 1m as $D$ is in the order of meters.

So now using Pythagoras Theorem,$$S_1P = \sqrt{ 1+ 10^{-6}}$$ and subtracting this value with 1m ie. the value we would have taken to be the length of $S_1P$ with the approximations, we get $4.99 x 10^{-7}$ ( I it put in a calculator to get the actual value). Again, under normal circumstances this difference between $qP$ and $S_1P$ is very insignificant, **BUT** this is exactly in the order of the wavelength of visible light!

I think its pretty safe to say when we are looking at the path difference to be in the order of $λ$, we cannot afford to neglect something which is in the range of 10^-7.

So I would like to know if there are any flaws with my analysis and want to know what I'm missing here, the thing which makes the approximation viable.
(PS this point has been bothering me quite a bit since the past few days so id really appreciate any input)

Comment: Here's a quick [latex guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1145828)

Comment: Ah thank you  for the guide I didn't know that's how its done. It looks way more legible after the formatting

Comment: Why is this question closed??

Answer (score 0):

From my optics classes, I always consider $\theta$ such that $\sin\theta \approx \tan\theta \approx \theta $. From that you can use trigonometric relations to express the path difference as a function of the different parameters of your experiments. So I never consider the path to be parallel, but the angle to be very small which is logical at this scale. And it leads to the fringe patterns solution you observe experimentally.

Of course the paths are not parallel otherwise they wouldn't interfere at all.

Comment: Could you let me know how the expression for path difference would look in your case?

Comment: You get $\delta = \frac{dx}{D}$ with $x$ the position of a point on the screen, noting $\delta$ the path difference